# Automatically add SQL Querys based on checkboxes input and text input - trying to build a search filtering system

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to build a filtering system that shows results based on text input and checkbox options selected by a user.

My database currently has 3 tables

table 1 : `brunches`
table 2 : `vibes`
table 3 : `cuisines`

`brunches contains a list of restaurants, and in the`brunchesvibes`contains vibes and`brunchescuisines`tables contains the food that the restaurants from`brunches` offers.

So for example

Table 1  - Brunches

```
id    Name 
1     Jamies Brunch
2     Roka 
3     Mcdonalds
```

Table 2  - Vibes

```
id  vibe      brunchid 
1   Arty      1
2   Luxury    1
3   Trendy    3
```

Table 3 - Cuisines

```
id  cuisines      brunchid 
1   BBQ            1
2   Japanese       1
3   British        3
```

As you can see all the tables match up via brunchid.

What I am trying to achieve is i have a bunch of checkboxes in a form, which contains a list of 'vibes' and 'cuisines', when a user checks the vibes and cuisines they want displayed, it should then run a query and show only those results.

this is the php code so far, however it doesn't work - when i select multiple options, it returns an sql error, because it is just doing an AND statement, that being said, I'm not sure if the way i've got it searching the vibes table is correct... and i'm not sure how to add OR statements when there are multiple options selected.

```
$type = $this->input->post("type");
$name = $this->input->post("brunchname");
$vibes = $this->input->post("vibes");
$cuisines = $this->input->post("cuisines");
$range = $this->input->post("range");

$sqlQuery = "SELECT b.*, host,
FROM brunches b
LEFT JOIN hosts ON hosts.id = b.hostid ";


if(! empty($vibes)) {

  foreach ($vibes as $v):
    $sqlQuery .= "WHERE b.id in (
    select bv.brunchid from brunchvibes bv where bv.vibe = '$v')";

  endforeach; 
}  

if(! empty($cuisines)) {

  foreach ($cuisines as $c):
    $sqlQuery .= "WHERE b.id in (
    select b.brunchid from brunchcuisines bc where bc.cuisine = '$c')";

  endforeach; 
}

if(! empty($name)) {
  $sqlQuery .= "name LIKE '%$name%')";

  endforeach;
}

$sqlQuery .=" AND approved ='1'";
```

Comment: How large is the data set? How many brunches, vibes, and cuisines?

Comment: Your tables seem to have names. Please add them.

Also, your loop seems a bit messed up.
To filter on vibes, first build a list of the selected vibe ids "1, 4, 5" and then use that in your query
WHERE v.id in ('$v')

Comment: it's not just about vibes, its about filtering based on the selected vibes & cuisines, i.e they could only show brunches that are Trendy & offer Japenese food.

Comment: you could try something like $sqlWhere = "";

 if(! empty($vibes)) {

  foreach ($vibes as $v):
     if(! empty($sqlWhere)) {
       $sqlWhere .= " AND "
     }
     $sqlWhere .= " b.id in (
       select bv.brunchid from brunchvibes bv where bv.vibe = '$v')";

  endforeach; 
}  for all three if's but you are vulnerable for sql injection. so you have to prepare and bind parameters instead addind vivbes and cuisines directly. so show please also what you are using for executing the sql statement